# How to use bash variables in sed command?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to do (in bash script):

```
NEWBASE=`echo $NAME | sed "s/${DIR}//g" | sed 's/.\///g'`
```

I read in the net, that I have to replace single quote with double quote. 
This is unfortunately not working. Why? 
 Thanks

Comment: Post an input along with expected output.

Comment: you are missing the final execution single quote... `

Comment: the final execution single quote is there, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is overkill for this. Use parameter expansion:

```
NEWBASE=${NAME//$DIR//}
NEWBASE=${NEWBASE//.\//}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your point?? I have to perform some string manipulations with sed.

Comment: I haven't posted all the sed executions. There is more than the 2 above

Comment: It's not what I expected but it's working! Thank you chepner

Comment: When possible, you want to use built-in shell commands rather than starting an external program. `sed` is appropriate if you have a file full of lines, all of which are processed identically, but when you are only echoing a single string, you can often use the shell itself to process it.

Comment: As a matter of fact I have multiple subdirectories full of images. I have to perform many tasks on this images like resizing, compressing and at the end rename them using directory names.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that bash and sed are two completely independent things. When you give bash a command, it first processes it according to its rules, in order to come up with a utility name and a set of arguments for that utility (in this case sed), and then calls the utility with the arguments.

Probably `$DIR` contains a slash character. Perhaps it looks something like `/usr/home/codyline/src`.

So when bash substitutes that into the argument to the sed command:

```
"s/${DIR}//g"
```

the result is

```
s//usr/home/codyline/src//g
```

which is what is then passed to sed. But sed can't understand that commabnd: it has (many) too many <kbd>/</kbd> characters.

If you really want to use sed for this purpose, you need to use a delimiter other than <kbd>/</kbd>, and it needs to be a character you are confident will never appear in `$DIR`. Fortunately, the sed `s` command allows you to use any character as a delimiter: whatever character follows the `s` is used as the delimiter. But there always must be exactly three of them in the command.

For example, you might believe that no directory path contains a colon (<kbd>:</kbd>), in which case you could use:

```
sed "s:${DIR}::g"
```

Of course, someday that will fail precisely because you have a directory with a colon in its name. So you could make things more general by using bash's substitute-and-replace feature to backslash-escape all the colons:

```
sed "s:${DIR//:/\:}::g"
```

But you could have used this bash feature in order to avoid the use of sed altogether:

```
NEWBASE=${NAME//$DIR}
```

Unfortunately, you can't nest bash substitute-and-replaces, so you need to do them sequentially:

```
NEWBASE=${NEWBASE//.\/}
```

Note: I used `${var//...}`, which is the equivalent of specifying the `g` flag in a sed `s` command, but I really don't know if it is appropriate. Do you really expect multiple instances of `$DIR` in a single path? If there are multiple instances, do you really want to remove all of them? You'll have to decide.

Comment: Thanks rici. I solved my problem like suggested by @chepner: `NEWBASE=${NAME//$DIR//}
NEWBASE=${NEWBASE//.\//}` and than executing sed tasks. It's not a one liner any more but it works.